# Getting a core dump from a simple C program

Tags: c

I'm trying to get the code working, and I don't know where's a mistake.  I've tried with references etc but it does not work.

```
void output(int t[],int n) {
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        printf("%d ",t[i]);
}
void swap(int *xp, int *yp) { 
    int temp = *xp; 
    *xp = *yp; 
    *yp = temp; 
} 
void func(int t[], int n) { 
    output(t,n);
}
void gen_data(int n) {
    FILE *data=fopen("dane.txt","w");
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) 
        fprintf(data,"%d ",rand()%200-100);
    fclose(data);
}

void gen_tab(int *tab, int n) {
    FILE *data=fopen("dane.txt","r");
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) 
        fscanf(data,"%d",&tab[i]);
    fclose(data);
}
void start(int tab[],int n,void (*f)(int,int)) {
    double a,b;
    a=(unsigned)time(NULL);
    output(tab,n); //OK
    f(tab,n);// CRASH

    b=(unsigned)time(NULL);
    double result=(b-a)/60;
    printf("result: %lf",result);
}
int main() {
    int flag;
    scanf("%d",&flag);
    gen_data(flag);
    int *t;
    t=(int*)malloc(flag*sizeof(int));
    gen_tab(t,flag);
    //output(t,flag);
    start(t,flag,func);
    free(t);
    return 0;
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: If it's C, why do you tag [tag:c++]?

Comment: With code like this C++ people can also easily answer

Comment: `void (*f)(int,int)` this is not the correct type for the function you are passing.

Comment: @Dimfred That's not relevant though.

Comment: @Dimfred If C++ people are looking for C questions to answer, they'll find it. Tagging with an unrelated language is not appropriate. What if Fortran people could help? Or Erlang? This is C code. It needs the C tag and only the C tag.

Comment: Did run your code in a **debugger** to see where that error occurs, then run it again with a breakpoint near that failure so you can step carefully ahead and watch what happens leading up to that point?

Comment: The most obvious mistakes first seen are a) not checking the return value from `fopen` and b) not checking the return value from `scanf`. Without knowing if there is [**garbage in**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in,_garbage_out) there is no way to tell why there might be **garbage out**.

Comment: But all functions from c works perfectly in c++, and by the way, this is not the topic to discuss. If u wan't help -> do it, not just complain about the tag.

Comment: like i said, it crashes  when i use function
```
f(tab,n)
```

Comment: We do like to give help! To those who post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem, with the input, the expected output, and the actual output in the question. You might benefit by reading the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I get (after adding the missing library headers) two compiler warnings for the line marked as crashing. Warning C4047: 'function': 'int' differs in levels of indirection from 'int *'. And warning C4024: 'f': different types for formal and actual parameter.

Comment: @Krzysioka solved by the third comment and an answer, actually.

Comment: Can you post dane.txt too so other people can run a test for you? Alternatively, you can copy & paste your code and dane.txt and diagnose it by yourself at https://segfault.stensal.com.   The cause of segfault should be reported once you run your code in the tool.

Comment: (Pro-tip: when posting here, try if you can to avoid txtspk, use correct English spellings, use correct case, and write a clear title that summarises the problem. This may reduce your downvotes, even if there are other issues with the question.)

Answer (score 2):

You should take a deeper look at your start() function definition.

```
void start(int tab[],int n,void (*f)(int,int))
```

The third argument which is a function requires two integers.
However, if I am not mistaken, you want to pass there an array. So I would recommend you to change that to:

```
void start(int tab[],int n,void (*f)(int[],int))
```